# Firebase admin sdk dependency on gradle causing boot layer error

Tags: gradle, firebase-admin

I'm trying to build a desktop app using javafx for extracting data from pdf and save the content as json in firebase. Adding the firebase admin sdk dependency on gradle causes build error. But it is working with maven projects.

I've created the gradle project using this guide- https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Intellij and for firebase admin sdk I've followed the official docs.But it keeps creating ResolutionException and mentions some modules.Adding dependencies or jars for those modules causes more module exceptions. I'm trying to avoid maven as it causes some conflicts with javafx which I also couldn't solve.

This is my current build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.5'
}

group 'com.tiptoptips'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.7.0'
}

javafx {
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml' ]
}

mainClassName = 'com.tiptoptips.MainApp'
```

and here is the error I get while running or building this project-

```
> Task :run FAILED
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.ResolutionException: Modules proto.google.common.protos 
and gax.grpc export package com.google.longrunning to module 
javafx.graphicsEmpty

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':run'.
> Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After about 4 days research, I found a way to solve it. I had to download the javafx-11 libs manually and add it to the project using vm options. I had to add javafx.controls and javafx.fxml manually. Then re-adding the firebase admin sdk into the gradle worked fine. I still couldn't get why intellij was showing firebase is missing module instead of locating the javafx files. Complete details can be found here- https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx